# LaTex error stating incomplete item list while creating a table

Tags: tables, itemize

I get an error in LaTex which states: "There are no entries found in a list you have created. Make sure you label list entries using the \item command, and that you have not used a list inside a table."

This is the table code created where the error shows up.

```
\begin{table}[H]

\centering

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}

\hline

\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\flushleft{\hspace{0.1cm}\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{image}}\hspace{1cm} \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}ABC\\ \\ ABC\\ ABC\\ \\ Shivanand\end{tabular}}} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textit{Approved} \\ \\ 2018-06-10\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textit{Examiner} \\ \\ ABC\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textit{Supervisor} \\ \\ ABC\end{tabular} \\ \hline
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textit{Commissioner} \\ \\ ABC \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textit{Contact Person} \\ \\ ABC\end{tabular} \\

\hline

\end{tabular}%

}

\end{table}
```

Could anyone enlighten me with the mistake? I don't see any list which I have created in the code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please do not post fragments, but complete compilable code samples (MWE). Btw: resizeboxing a table is always a bad idea.

Comment: Could you please also add a sketch of the desired output? From your code I find it quite hard to understand, how the final table should look like.

Comment: This is completely unrelated to the original post's behavior, but if you have arrived at this post and are not using multicolumn but still getting the error, check that you have no linebreaks in caption---i.e., the \\.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error comes from the `tabular` inside the `\multicolumn`.

However, I also think you're complicating your life with all those `tabular` environments inside the main `tabular`, in your case they are useless.

Please note that to have some vertical space between two table rows you don't need to add an empty row, but you can simply write `\\[some_dimension]`.

Moreover, instead of resizing the table `\textwidth` I used a `tabularx` environment.

I also added `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` in the preamble and a `\rule{0pt}{11pt}` in the header for better vertical spacing.

I hope the result is what you need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]

    \centering

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth, valign=c]{example-image}} 
                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell{\rule{0pt}{11pt}\textbf{ABC}\\[10pt] \textbf{ABC}\\ \textbf{ABC}\\[10pt] \textbf{Shivanand}}}\\
            \hline
            \textit{Approved} & \textit{Examiner} & \textit{Supervisor}\\[14pt] 
            2018-06-10 & ABC & ABC \\ 
            \hline
            & \textit{Commissioner} & \textit{Contact Person} \\[14pt] 
            & ABC & ABC \\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}  
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]